# R how to ggplot frequency every 2 hours in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, frequency

I've following dataset:

```
time          tta    
08:20:00       1
21:30:00       5
22:00:00       1
22:30:00       1
00:25:00       1
17:00:00       5
```

I would like to plot bar chart using ggplot so that the x-axis has every every 2 hours(00:00:00,02:00:00,04:00:00 and so on) and y-axis has frequency for a factor tta (1 and 5).

[x-axis should be 00-01,01-02,... so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT0gR.png)

Comment: So what's your question? What did you try?

Comment: Q: how to plot frequency of tta using time data for every two hour interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approached this using the `xts` package, but then found that it does not offer flooring the time.  Hence, I conclude `lubridate` to be more practical here, also because `ggplot` does not understand `xts` objects right away.  Both packages help you transforming time data in many ways.

Use `xts::align.time` or `lubridate::floor_date` to shift your times to the next/previous full hour/day/etc.

Either way, you aggregate the data before you pass it to ggplot.  You can use `sum` to sum up `tta`, or just use `length` to count the number of occurences, but in the latter case you could also use `geom_histogram` on the time series only.  You can carefully shift the bars in `ggplot` with `position_nudge` to represent a period rather than just sitting centered on a point of time.  You sould specify `scale_x_time(labels = ..., breaks = ...)` in the plot.

Data:

```
time <- c(
  "08:20:00",
  "21:30:00",
  "22:00:00",
  "22:30:00",
  "00:25:00",
  "17:00:00"
)
time <- as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
tta <- c(1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5)
```

Using `xts`:

```
library(xts)
myxts <- xts(tta, order.by = time)
myxts_aligned <- align.time(myxts, n = 60*60*2)  # shifts all times to the next full
# 2 hours
myxts_agg <- period.apply(myxts_aligned,
                           INDEX = endpoints(myxts, "hours", 2),
                           FUN = sum)  # sums up every two hours
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = index(myxts_agg), y = myxts_agg[, 1])) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 60*60*2,  # one bar to be 2 hours wide
           position = position_nudge(x = -60*60),  # shift one hour to the left
           # so that the bar represents the actual period
           colour = "black") +
  scale_x_time(labels = function(x) strftime(x, "%H:%M"),
               breaks = index(myxts_agg)) +  # add more breaks manually if you like
  scale_y_continuous()  # to escape the warning of ggplot not knowing
  # how to deal with xts object
```

Using `lubridate`:

```
require(lubridate)
require(tidyverse)
mydf <- data.frame(time = time, tta = tta)
mydf_agg <-
  mydf %>%
    group_by(time = floor_date(time, "2 hours")) %>%
    summarise(tta_sum = sum(tta), tta_freq = n())
ggplot(mydf_agg, aes(x = time, y = tta_sum)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 60*60*2,  # one bar to be 2 hours wide
           position = position_nudge(x = 60*60),  # shift one hour to the *right*
           # so that the bar represents the actual period
           colour = "black") +
  scale_x_time(labels = function(x) strftime(x, "%H:%M"),
               breaks = mydf_agg$time)  # add more breaks manually if you like
```

After all, allmost the same:

[image: xts and lubridate two hour aggregation]

Answer (score 0):

use the `floor_date` function from `lubridate`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

your_df %>% group_by(floor_date(time,"2 hours")) %>% count(tta)
```

and then `ggplot` with `geom_col` from there

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "c('hms', 'difftime')"

Comment: I guess with the way you have the `time` column, lubridate can't do `floor_date`. does your data span over multiple days? If not, you could just take the first two digits of the `time` column using a substring

Comment: time data span over several years but it should not play any role because I'm going to use time only variable with factor variable. How to group time data into two hour range (bin)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
```

Make sure the class for your timestamp is *POSxx*

```
> class(df$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Then use the s**cale_x_datetime** function as follows.

```
gg +
scale_x_datetime(expand = c(0, 0), breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

On this case, it will space the brakes on the x axis, every one hour and the labels will look 09:00 for example.